# C linux server blocking

Tags: c, sockets, serversocket

Server:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>    //write
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "shared.h"

char **serverFolderTree;
int serverFoldersNumber;

FILES *fls;
int serverFilesNumber;

void getFolders()
{
    i = 0;
    serverFolderTree = allocateFolderTree();
    serverFoldersNumber = getFolderTree(serverFolderTree, "", SERVER_ROOT);
}

void getFiles()
{
    i=0;
    fls = getFileList(fls, "", SERVER_ROOT);    
    serverFilesNumber = i;
}

int main()
{
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , read_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char client_message[2000], tmp[2000];

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    acceptNew:

    //Accept and incoming connection
    printf("\nWaiting for incoming connections...\n");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    //accept connection from an incoming client
    client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Connection accepted\n");

    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(client_sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
    if(!strcmp(client_message, FOLDER_TREE_REQ))//folder tree requested
    {
        printf("Recieved: folder tree req\n");
        getFolders();

        //send folder tree nr
        sprintf(tmp,"%d",serverFoldersNumber);
        write(client_sock , tmp , strlen(tmp)+1);

        //send folder tree elements
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<serverFoldersNumber;i++)
        {
        //strcpy(tmp, serverFolderTree[i]);

        sprintf(tmp,"%s",serverFolderTree[i]);
        printf("%s\n", tmp);
        write(client_sock , tmp , 1000);
        }
    }
    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        printf("Client disconnected\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    //goto acceptNew;//listen for another connection
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
#include<stdio.h> //printf
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>    //socket
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "shared.h"

char **clientFolderTree, **serverFolderTree;
int clientFoldersNumber, serverFoldersNumber;

FILES *fls;
int clientFilesNumber;

void getFolders()
{
    i = 0;
    clientFolderTree = allocateFolderTree();
    serverFolderTree = allocateFolderTree();
    clientFoldersNumber = getFolderTree(clientFolderTree, "", CLIENT_ROOT);
}

void getFiles()
{
    i=0;
    fls = getFileList(fls, "", CLIENT_ROOT);    
    clientFilesNumber = i;
}

int main()
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char message[1000] , server_reply[2000];
    bool k=true; 

    //Create socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Connected\n");

    //req folder tree
    getFolders();

    strcpy(message, FOLDER_TREE_REQ);
    if( send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
    {
         puts("Send failed");
         return 1;
    }

    //Receive folder tree number
    recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0);
    serverFoldersNumber = atoi(server_reply);

    printf("server fld nr: %d\n", serverFoldersNumber);
    //recieve folder tree
    for(i=0;i<serverFoldersNumber;i++)
    {
    if(recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
    {
      puts("recv failed");
      break;
    }

    printf("Got: %s\n", server_reply);
    }

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

The server says he sent the list (and prints it correctly) but on the client side it recieves `folderNumber` (printed it and works it's 10) but when reciving the tree it prints "Got: " less than 3 times.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Ignoring the return value from recv() is never a good idea......

Comment: Whilst you send lots of times, are you actually losing any data (i.e. if each read exactly one record, or is it multiple?)

Comment: @RowlandShaw - or less than one, or 2.7?

Comment: each read should get a tree[i] but it doesn't read them, I've managed to get something if  I changed the length I send/read but not all the results

Comment: Closely read the man-pages for `recv()`/`send()` and learn that those two functions do not necessarily receive/send as much bytes as they were told to, but few. So looping around such calls counting until all data expected or a terminator had been received/sent is a good idea, not to say an essential necessity.

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming that a call to recv() will load a single, complete folder string into the server_reply buffer, ie. you need to call recv() exactly as many times are there are folder strings.

That will not work.

TCP does not know, or care, about null-terminated C-strings.  It transfers octet/byte streams only.  If, say,  you have 50 folder names that together take up 8000 bytes, it is possible, (though unlikely), that you may have to call recv() 8000 times to get all the data, each call returning only one byte.

Edit:

Sending the folders is not a problem - you send how many strings, then the strings.

Sending the request to the server is a problem:

> if( send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0)

will not send the null-terminator.  This probably works first-time by the side-effect of the server buffer array being initialized to 0.

Receiving the request at the server is a problem:

> read_size = recv(client_sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)

May read all of the FOLDER_TREE_REQ, or one char of it, or anything in between.

Receiving the size at the client is a problem:

> recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0);

may return the entire ASCII number, or the first character of it, or anything in between, or the entire ASCII number plus some part/s of the folder string/s.

> write(client_sock , tmp , 1000);

will try to send the entire 1000 bytes, with your null-terminated folder name at the start and uninitialized/leftover bytes at the end.

..and so on.

You should fix all your code so that it makes no assumptions about messages any longer than one byte.

You should fix all your code so that it does not depend upon complete, null-terminated strings being transferred.

You should fix all your code so that is does not matter if data sent by X send() calls is received in one recv() call, X recv() calls or >X recv() calls.

Sorry if that seems messy, but that's life with TCP.  IF you don't lock up everything so that it cannot go wrong, it WILL screw up, probably on someone else's installation, even if it seem to work OK in your testing.

Comment: so for char **x how can I send x[i] when x[i] is allocated (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*255*100) ?

Comment: I've managed to get something if I changed the length I send/read but not all the results